# logo disappear in mobile Chrome browser

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am facing a problem with a logo of a wordpress site. logo is not showing in google chrome browser when i browse it with my android mobile .  But when i use firefox browser in my mobile it is ok . If you check its responsiveness  by desktop you will see that logo is showing properly in mobile device by all browser including google chrome  .  but when it is browsed by chrome browser in mobile phone its logo disappear. Site url http://www.caledonianbuilding.co.uk/ Is there anyone to solve it .

Answer (score 0):

According to the Inspector, the following style definition is hiding the logo:

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), not all, not all, not all {
    #alterna-header .logo-default {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: hello mevius . thanks for your comments . but I check it by changing display none to display block . and also delete this code . but its not working.